# Create a variable based on n other variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have a dataset in SAS that has 10 variables on the basis of which I would like to create a new flag. If any of the class columns is greater than 0 then its name should come in the flag as given in the picture below.

[image]

Can someone please help me on how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID Class_Tom Class_Sim Class_Sam Class_Jack Class_Des Class_Pun Class_Jun Class_Kick Class_Pop Class_Neo;
infile datalines dlm = '|' dsd;
datalines;
101|95|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
102|82|  |27|  |  |  |  |  |  |  
103|  |56|  |  |  |61|  |80|  |  
104|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
;

data want(drop = i);
   set have;
   array c{*} class_:;
   length flag $200;
   flag = '';
   do i = 1 to dim(c);
      if c[i] then flag = catx(' | ', flag, vname(c[i]));
   end; 
run;
```